# Programmatic access to Excel file with ACE driver with password protected file in VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm trying to access to the data contained on a Excel sheet programmatically. I would like to do it without showing the Excel application and am using the ACE OLEDB driver to communicate with the workbook.

When the Excel file is not password protected, the following code works:

```
Dim fDialog As New OpenFileDialog()
With fDialog
    .Title = "Seleccionar archivos";
    .Filter = "Archivo Excel (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm)|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm"
    .Multiselect = False
    .InitialDirectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\Datos"
    .FilterIndex = 1
    .RestoreDirectory = True
    If .ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Call Ver_Datos_Excel(.FileName)
    End If
End

'...

Private Sub Ver_Datos_Excel(sFichero_Excel As String)
    Try
        Dim cadconex As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
        Source=" & sFichero_Excel & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro; HDR=YES"""
        Dim conorigen As New OleDbConnection(cadconex)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [Desglose$]", conorigen)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        conorigen.Open() '~~~> This line fails only when the file is password protected

        '...

End Sub
```

**Note:** I've discarded the use of open(...) Workbooks method because it is shows the Excel application.

Comment: ADO doesn't work on password protected workbooks. The best you can do is to try it through GetObject on Excel application (but that's not easy/trivial).

Comment: At least you do use ACE and not Interop